# Excel: VBA to delete group of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with one column with data. Something like:

```
21/07/2017
DEF
GHI
Field 7
SOMETHING HERE
MORE TEXT
21/07/2017
DEF
GHI
Field 7
```

This is repeated a few thousand times. What I am looking for is all rows between and including 21/07/2017 and Field 7 to be deleted and for the rows to be moved up.

I've tried a few things but now back to a blank canvas! Any hints?

Thanks

***CODE I TRIED***

I get an Overflow error

```
Sub deleteRows()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    RowCount = 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    For Each rw In sh.Rows

      If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "21/07/2017" Then
        a = RowCount
      End If
      If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "Field 7" Then
        b = RowCount
        Rows(a & ":" & b).Delete
      End If

      RowCount = RowCount + 1

    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Also, what is the text to be removed? Does it follow a pattern? Is it the same text repeatedly? Is this a one time operation or do you have to repeat this? Dummy data is not helpful in this case

Comment: With your example I would look for and delete cells with more than 3 characters in. That is why it is important to post accurate data

Comment: Amended. As I said, the rows to be removed are the ones between and including 21/07/2017 and Field 7. Just those rows.

Comment: Okay, firing up Excel. I'll get back to you in a few minutes

Comment: is that true date or a string that looks like a date?

Comment: You delete row 3. Row 4 now moves up & becomes row 3. You start looking at what is _now_ row 4, but that _was_ row 5 before, so you're skipping examining a row. When deleting rows, **always** start at the bottom & work your way up. Otherwise, that will be the next bug you're chasing down.

Comment: Peeps answered it first, but @FreeMan is correct. Also, you loop through each row without checking if you've got to the end so will keep going on processing empty rows unnecessarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will only loop as many times as the pair exists and delete each block as a whole.

The loop ends the first time that both are not found in the remaining values.

```
Sub myDelete()
Dim str1 As string
Dim str2 As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

str1 = "21/07/2017"
str2 = "Field 7"

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet18") 'change to your worksheet
Set rng = ws.Range("A:A")


Do
    i = 0: j = 0
    On Error Resume Next
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str1, rng, 0)
        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(str2, rng, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i > 0 And j > 0 Then
        ws.Rows(i & ":" & j).Delete
    End If
Loop Until i = 0 Or j = 0
End Sub
```

If your date is a true date then change str1 to Double:

```
Dim str1 As Double
```

and then assign it as such:

```
str1 = CDbl(DateSerial(2017, 7, 21))
```